# Do I need to fill out a new DS160 because of an outdated photo and a slight lack of information?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

PS. I have paid the visa fee and set up an interview date. Therefore, I think I cannot modify the existing DS160. However, I can create a new one and maybe update it using https://ais.usvisa-info.com or update it at the consulate?

My questions are:

1. I used an old photo, but I will bring a new photo with me to the interview. Should I create a new DS160 with a recent picture?
2. I said "I don't know" in the field that asks for my specialty in the military. A better answer would be "None", but I am not 100% certain that is true. My time in the military lasted 3 weeks and it was only basic training, I believe. It was paid military service, which exempts me from most of the military duty. What should I say for this field?
3. I wrote "Gonna book an Airbnb" and a zip code in the field that asks for where I am going to be staying in the US. Should I book a place just so I can fill this out?

Or are these minor things? Maybe I am being paranoid? After COVID, I believe *most* people who applied for this visa from my nationality have been rejected, so I am trying to be careful.

Comment: Please tag your nationality also.